# how to put shinyApp html out in PDF or other format

Tags: r, shiny, pdf-generation

Here is an example of my code that I would like to store eventually in PDF.

```
library(shiny)
library(arsenal)
library(knitr)
library(survival)
```

# Creating random dataset with columns and an identifier 
 for samples

```
random <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(5:100, 10)))

samples <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1, 1)))

randomdf <- merge(samples,random, by= "row.names")
rm(random, samples)
```

## I removed the column with row names to get a better example of the table

```
randomdf$Row.names <- NULL
```

## create the table with Shiny

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(tableOutput("table")), # creating a page with fluidpage
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderTable({
      as.data.frame(summary(tableby(randomdf$replicate.10..sample.0.1..1..~., 
                                    data = randomdf, 
                                    numeric.stats=c("medianq1q3"), 
                                    numeric.test="kwt"), 
                            text = "html",
                            digits = 2))
    },striped=TRUE, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)

  }
)
```

I have found the code below that should generate a PDF but I'm not sure how to implement it with the previous code.

```
shinyApp(
        ui <- fluidPage(tableOutput("table"),
                 downloadButton("report","Generate report")), 

  server <-function(input, output) {
    rendertable to indicate that
    inputs change

    output$table <- renderTable({
     as.data.frame(summary(tableby(randomdf$replicate.10..sample.0.1..1..~., 
                                    data = randomdf, 
                                    numeric.stats=c("medianq1q3"), 
                                    numeric.test="kwt"), 
                            text = "html",
                            digits = 2))
    },striped=TRUE, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```

# here is where I now added the new piece of code

```
 output$report <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "report.pdf",
      content = function(file) {
        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
        file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

        params = list(n= input$table)

        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                          params = params,
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
      }
    )
  }
)
```

I now have the "generate report" button indeed in my html but I cannot produce a report due to the following error:

> Warning in normalizePath(path, winslash = winslash, mustWork =
>   mustWork) :
>   path[1]="/var/folders/4g/ld58jxf94s74vrcf_1gd07bh0000gn/T//RtmphCZeLD/report.Rmd":
>   No such file or directory Warning: Error in abs_path: The file
>   '/var/folders/4g/ld58jxf94s74vrcf_1gd07bh0000gn/T//RtmphCZeLD/report.Rmd'
>   does not exist.   [No stack trace available]

Comment: did you have a look at : https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html

Comment: Yes but but I struggled with implementing my code in there. If you could point me in the right direction I can give it another try

Answer (score 0):

I used R Markdown instead which perfectly does what I need

```
table_one <- tableby(Sample ~., data = Random, 
                     numeric.stats=c("medianq1q3"), 
                     numeric.test="kwt", 
                     digits = 2,
                     digits.p= 2)

summary(sort(table_one, increasing = TRUE), text=TRUE, title = "test")
```